Blend a list of colors with hues from 0 to 1 in increments of 0.1
This question from a course has proven too hard for me

Blend a list of colors with hues from 0 to 1 in increments of 0.1.

I tried this
Blend[Table[{Hue[n]},{n,0,1,0.1}]]

but the output is considered erroneous.
Maybe you have some deeper insight into my failed attempt. Thank you very much.

Another way is just Hue[0.5]

You added an extra layer of curly braces.
Blend[Table[Hue[n], {n, 0, 1, 0.1}]]



The issue with your code is that the Table function creates a nested list structure, and Blend expects a flat list of colors. Additionally, Hue should not be enclosed in a list. Here's how you can correct your code:
Blend[Table[Hue[n], {n, 0, 1, 0.1}]]

